# What can I do if I still have not recieved the rights review from ACM?

Tags: acm

We finished shepherding a paper recently and we still have not received the Association for Computing and Machinery (ACM) rights review to finalize our camera-ready which is due very soon. Our hotcrp page says accepted and we are cleared but we still have not received the rights review. I have reached out to the publicity chairs for the rights review email and they claim to have sent it but I have not received it. I don't know who else to ask because they have yet to reply to my emails where I ask again for the rights review link. I also do not want to turn in a not ready camera ready, what should I do?

Comment: You are correct, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

They claim to have sent an email that you didn't receive? First, check your spam box. It's quite possible that automated emails sent by conference organizers get caught in that.

It that doesn't help, escalate to the program chairs. They accepted your paper, they want the publication process to succeed, so to make it hang on a rights review email that may or may not have been sent is not in their best interest.